# Can Light Really be Matter?

Tags: energy, visible-light, electricity, matter

I remember during my early education being taught that light is a form of matter.  This has always seemed counter-intuitive to me.

Comment: Then why would fission reactions produce energy, if not for the mass defect?

Comment: What is your title supposed to have to do with the question you asked?

Comment: More to the point: what *is* the question?

Comment: Consider the Michelson–Morley experiment results.

Comment: Matter (an ill-defined term in physics) usually means anything with a mass, and whether you like it or not, $E=mc^2$.

Comment: Energy is a property of matter. Mass is also a property of matter. Both are to be used like the word "red", which is also a property.  One can therefor say "the chair (which is matter) has a red color" and "the chair has a mass of 5kg" and "the chair has a (potential or kinetic) energy of 17J", but that doesn't make the color red or mass or energy equivalent to matter. They all are and stay properties of matter at all times. In relativity we learn, though, that the three properties of mass, energy and momentum are linked to each other.

Comment: @lemon: Why do you think that matter is ill-defined in physics? It seems rather well defined to me by "that which occupies space and possesses rest mass". Rest mass is an invariant for all inertial observers. Radiation doesn't possess rest mass and it doesn't occupy space. Radiation will go right trough itself. Now, if you want to cite Einstein's result about the relationship between _rest mass_, _momentum_ and _energy_, please do it properly and completely: $E^2=(pc)^2+(m_0c^2)^2$.

Comment: @CuriousOne, [first paragraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter).

Comment: At some point in my education it was said that energy is matter.  This is what I'm rejecting.

Comment: @lemon: Wikipedia can be edited by everybody. Please feel free to correct that nonsense. Rest mass is a very well defined concept and so are inertial systems which are completely based on the motion of pieces of matter. That's also a way to define matter: "That which can be used to define an inertial system.". Radiation can't.

Comment: No, at some point in your education it was probably said that energy and mass are equivalent, which is almost true, but not quite, as the full formula demonstrates. The problem with the English version is that "mass" and "matter" sound similar, even though they are not the same thing. The other problem with these things is that it doesn't really matter if the teacher tells students the right thing, most will misunderstand it, anyway. That is _not_ a jab at you. I misunderstood these things for many years, myself, and I still don't understand the more advanced concepts. It's simply tough!

Comment: @dmckee the question is "is light a form of matter?"  How do you not see that??

Answer (score 2):

> **Can Light Really be Matter?**

I suppose it depends on what you mean by "be".

[Matter will be created from light within a year, claim scientists](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2014/may/18/matter-light-photons-electrons-positrons)

> **It just is counter-intuitive to me.**

This is the fallacy of reasoning from personal incredulity. It isn't a good guide.

I find most of QM and relativity counter-intuitive - it doesn't seem to be a simple extrapolation of what I see when I throw rocks into puddles. Nevertheless I don't have any insurmountable difficulty accepting that QM and relativity are better models of reality.

> **Energy cannot possibly be matter.**

Well, if you take that as a premise you have an answer to your question. I would suggest you need a proof for this premise.

> **It seems far more likely that energy is transported across matter**

How do you explain sunlight?

The whole notion of [luminiferous aether](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminiferous_aether) was disproved conclusively a long time ago.

> **electricity across copper wire**

Introducing the concept of electric current may be muddying the waters rather than helping to clarify your question.

In an electric circuit, [energy is not carried through wires by electrons](http://www.furryelephant.com/content/electricity/visualizing-electric-current/surface-charges-poynting-vector/).

> **or particles in air; light across particles in air.**

Light can also travel across a vacuum.

> **Even electrons must be charged particles.**

This statement does not seem to be well connected with your question or your line of reasoning.

You may be arguing that electrons are physical particles, therefore photons must be. But electrons and photons are very different things, they are not equivalent.

> **I know this question is extremely assertive.**

It is certainly full of assertions.

Comment: At some point, everything thoroughly understood is/becomes intuitive.  Aether is/was always an incomplete concept.  The more likely reality is that space (not vacuum) is the finest form of matter.  Electrons at one end of copper wire are at once reactive due to reactions at the other end and in between.  Energy is energy.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. Light isn't matter.

Matter is generally described by fermions, light is described as a boson. These are different. Though they have qualities in common, for example energy or mass or spin.

Interestingly, Heisenberg judged that energy was 'equivalent' to the ancient principle of fire.

Comment: I'm not ignoring this answer.  I want to look into it.

Comment: I will maintain though, that there is exactly one energy.  Everything else is reactive to it.

Comment: Do you have a reference for your last sentence, it sounds like an interesting piece of history; what did Heisenberg mean exactly.

Comment: @RodVance: Yes, memory.  If you mean a citation, then no.

Comment: @B.JohnJones: Energy is _defined_ as the ability of a system to perform work. This makes it an observer dependent property of systems.

Comment: @CuriousOne: but observation depends on energy.

Comment: @B.JohnJones: Yes, it does, but that doesn't guarantee that you will always observe the same amount of energy. Kinetic energy depends on the relative motion between the system and the observer. We get quite a few questions about that because it seems like such a counterintuitive concept after all the talk about energy conservation, but that's a simple misunderstanding. Energy is conserved in closed systems when viewed from the same observer. It is not conserved between different observers.